# Insert a property value or variable in description of @ManagedOperation annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have the following class

```
public class MyClass {

   @Value("${printing.duration.seconds}")
   private int duration;

   @ManagedOperation(description = "Printing will be enabled for ***Insert Here*** seconds")
   public void print() {
   //
   }

}
```

How can I insert `duration` value in the description ?